# Cannot use addEventListener() on a createElement() (a button) after displaying it in the DOM (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, createelement

I am creating a Javascript framework recently and I am facing two problems that I don't understand at all. When I create a new button with `createElement()` in Javascript, I can't place it inside several elements at the same time without killing the "click" event (if this is an `id`, it works).

(Note : `"button.onclick = function()"` doesn't work either)

Here is the code : (I don't want to use any libraries)

```js
function createButton() {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "YOOOO";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button.style.color = "white";

    // Problem Two : If I click on the button, nothing happends
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        alert(e.target);
    }, false);

    var clas = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    Array.from(clas).forEach(element => {
        element.appendChild(button);
        element.innerHTML += ""; // First problem : If I don't do this, the button does not appear in the first div. I have no idea why !
    });
}
createButton();
```

```css
 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.2);
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>bug</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="test" id="1" style="padding: 50px;">
    <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="test" id="2" style="padding: 50px;">
    <span>2</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- `element.innerHTML += "";`, where `element` refers to the button's *parent*, will force the parent to re-parse its contents from their HTML string, thus corrupting any existing handlers on child elements. The element the listener is attached to will be removed from the DOM and replaced with a different one; the new one does not have the listener.
- When you do `appendChild`, if the element being appended already exists in the DOM, it'll be removed from where it existed previously before being appended to its new location. Since you only do `document.createElement('button')` once, without the `innerHTML += ''`, the button gets removed from its first position when appended to the second.

Create the button inside the loop instead, and both problems are solved.

```js
function createButton() {
  var clas = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  Array.from(clas).forEach(element => {

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "YOOOO";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button.style.color = "white";

    // Problem Two : If I click on the button, nothing happends
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      alert(e.target);
    }, false);
    element.appendChild(button);

  });
}
createButton();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.2);
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="1" style="padding: 50px;">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="test" id="2" style="padding: 50px;">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Or, making the code a bit prettier:

```js
function createButton() {
  for (const parent of document.querySelectorAll('.test')) {
    const button = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
    button.textContent = "YOOOO";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button.style.color = "white";
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      console.log(e.target);
    });
  }
}
createButton();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.2);
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="1" style="padding: 50px;">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="test" id="2" style="padding: 50px;">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: First creating **and appending** the buttons, to only then alter the appearance and text content is a really bad idea, performance-wise.

Comment: It's not in a performance-critical tight loop here, so it should be a non-issue, right? I prefer the concise version when it fits, which it seems to do here. Repainting also occurs only once all synchronous JS is complete, IIRC

Comment: Thank you ! It solved my problem, i will do something like that

Answer (score 0):

Your button is a single instance, and repeatedly calling

```
element.appendChild(button);
```

just *moves* it in the DOM repeatedly.

Your subsequent call to

```
element.innerHTML += "";
```

removes that reference from the DOM and instead creates a new `button` from its `outerHTML`. That is also where your added event listener gets lost.

If you need more than one button, your also need to **create more than one** button.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you delegate and clone

I think I already posted this answer for you a few days ago

```js
function createButton() {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.classList.add("redwhite");
  button.innerHTML = "YOOOO";
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".test")].forEach(element => {
    element.appendChild(button.cloneNode(true));
  });
}
createButton();
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("redwhite")) {
    console.log(tgt.closest("div").id)
  }  
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.2);
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.redwhite {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="test" id="1" style="padding: 50px;">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="test" id="2" style="padding: 50px;">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you. And this is my first post on stackoverflow, I hope my question hasn't been posted my someone else before me, i found nothing